# Importing Textfile as Matrix

Tags: octave

i'm trying to import a txt-File to octave which contains a matrix of data.
The matrix looks like this:

```
49       ..1. ...1.......... .....       49
47       ..12 ...1...... ... .....       47
45       ..12....1...... 2....1...       45
43      ....2....1...... 2...1....       43
41      .1..2.. .........2. .1.....      41
39      .1.12.2....1.....2. .1.....      39
37      .1..2.22...1.....2. .1.....      37
35      .1. 2222...2....2....1.1...      35
33      ....22.2...2....2....12....      33
31      ....22.2...2..........21...      31
29      .....2.2...2.....2....21...      29
27     ........222222....2....21....     27
25     .......22.2222....2.22.2.....     25
23     .......22.2222....2.2..2.....     23
21     .......222.222....2.2........     21
19     ........22.222....2..........     19
17    ..........2.2.2...22...........    17
15    ...............................    15
13    .......................2.......    13
11    .......................2......2    11
 9   ........................2.....222    9
 7 . ................. ..... ......222.   7
 5 ..................           ....1..   5
 3 ....... .........               ....   3
 1                                        1
```

This is actually map/coordinate system (y-axis=azimuth, x-axis=latitude), which i have to plot. (blank=no data, .=no effects, 1=weak effects, 2=strong eff.)

The result should look like [this](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/7/18/2e341cde0799e7cc0003a296d8afd73a-full.png)

Because i failed to import this txt-File, i changed it into this.

```
49;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;2;3;2;1;2;2;2;3;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;1;2;2;2;2;2;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;49
47;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;2;3;4;1;2;2;2;3;2;2;2;2;2;2;1;2;2;2;1;2;2;2;2;2;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;47
45;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;2;3;4;2;2;2;2;3;2;2;2;2;2;2;1;4;2;2;2;2;3;2;2;2;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;45
43;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;2;2;2;4;2;2;2;2;3;2;2;2;2;2;2;1;4;2;2;2;3;2;2;2;2;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;43
39;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;3;2;3;4;2;4;2;2;2;2;3;2;2;2;2;2;4;2;1;2;3;2;2;2;2;2;1;1;1;1;1;1;39
37;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;3;2;2;4;2;4;4;2;2;2;3;2;2;2;2;2;4;2;1;2;3;2;2;2;2;2;1;1;1;1;1;1;37
```

and so on.
This is working with my code.

```
RawMap = dlmread('C:\Desktop\2576.map', ';', 0:80, 0:24)
Map = flipud(RawMap)
pcolor(Map(:,2:end-1))
```

To this automatically i don't want to the change the code. So i need to get the original file imported. 
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: You are going to need to write your own reader/parser reading lines one by one.

Comment: I would advise you to pre-process your text file (looks like what you did already), and replace the dots and blanks by numbers (e.g. 9 and 0 respectively), then when read it in as a rectangular character array, throw out the first and last two entries of each row, and convert to numbers (e.g. by subtracting `'0'` from the results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach to parse the file meaningfully:

```
S = fileread('testo.txt');
S = strsplit (S, "\n");
S = strvcat( S );
S = double(S);
S = S(:, 4:end-4);

S( S == double(" ") ) = 0;
S( S == double(".") ) = 1;
S( S == double("1") ) = 2;
S( S == double("2") ) = 3;

pcolor(S); axis ij;
```

Comment: Great! Works perfect. Thank you!